# Cyclic rule for graded differential forms

Tags: differential-forms, supergeometry

I know that if I have a zero 3 form on a manifold, say $f= dx^a dx^b dx^c f_{abc} = 0$ then it follows that its coefficients obey the cyclic permutation relation: $f_{abc} + f_{bca} + f_{cab} = 0$. Now I want to get this formulae for forms on graded manifolds (I suppose that it will get some correction signs) but I struggle to do so. My conventions are such that I treat differential forms on a supermanifold $M$ as functions on $T[1]M$, so that $deg(dx^a) = deg(x^a) + 1$.

Comment: I don't think I understand your first claim. For the Levi-Civita tensor (say, on three dimensional Euclidean space with cartesian coordinates) $\epsilon_{123}+\epsilon_{231}+\epsilon_{312}=3$.